# What is the correct format to insert uuids into a json column within a Postgres script?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, jsonb

I want to insert variables of type UUID in a Postgres script into a column of type "jsonb".
The table looks like:

```
create table entity ( id bigint primary key, tags jsonb );
```

The script looks like:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  tagid1 UUID := '77170ed4-4d39-4799-ad22-750e57a11833';
  tagid2 UUID := '890b96ad-c595-4b6e-9e49-cad234190fda';

  insert into entity( id, tags ) VALUES ( 1, array_to_json(tagid1::uuid[]) );
  insert into entity( id, tags ) VALUES ( 2, array_to_json(tagid1, tagid2::uuid[]) );
END $$
```

This script aborts with "ERROR: cannot convert type uuid into type uuid[]"

Comment: You say you want to insert a single UUID and then try to cast that single UUID as an array. Which is it?

Comment: In Java JPA this is a list of uuids "List<UUID> tags". So both inserts should create a JSON array. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array, either use an array constructor or a literal.

```
SELECT array_to_json(array['77170ed4-4d39-4799-ad22-750e57a11833', '890b96ad-c595-4b6e-9e49-cad234190fda']);

SELECT array_to_json('{77170ed4-4d39-4799-ad22-750e57a11833,890b96ad-c595-4b6e-9e49-cad234190fda
clwrota_test'> }');
```

Note - you probably don't want either of those if your application is providing an array in the first place - just `array_to_json(<placeholder>)`.

Note - you probably want "jsonb" rather than "json" - see the manuals for details.

Comment: Hi Richard. I need to put variables into the function "array_to_json" for insert. Your example uses strings. Could you please modify it using variables as in my question? BTW column is of type jsonb.